# can't run jQuery functions after appending jQuery from same file

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I'm appending into my page multiple scripts including jQuery, jQuery migrate... all from same `.js` file

this is how it looks:

```
function appendScript(pathToScript, run) {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var js = document.createElement("script");
    js.type = "text/javascript";
    if(run == true){
        js.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 'complete') runFunctions();
        }
        js.onload = runFunctions;
    }
    js.src = pathToScript;
    head.appendChild(js);
}
appendScript("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js");
appendScript("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.3.0.min.js", true);
function runFunctions(){
    console.log('test') // all good till here
    // here i have only jquery functions
    $('#myDiv').addClass('test'); 
    alert("this doesn't work");
    ....
}
```

My problem is that I can't run `$(document).ready` or any jQuery function, only javascript.

Tried with timeout too. Also I already have 1 x `$(window).bind("load", function(){...}` so I don't need 1 more

Comment: It seems odd to append to the `<head>` like this. Are you writing an extension?

If not, then can you create a [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: [link to jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/og3djrb5/2/) I use a platform where I don't have access to head and can't use more than 1 single .js file :(

Comment: If my response below answers your question, you can click the green checkmark to mark it as the best answer. Otherwise, I can revise if it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since jQuery Migrate depends on jQuery, you need to wait until loading the next script.

Here is a working example (I also cleaned up some variables).

```
function appendScript(src, callback) {
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  if (callback) {
    script.onload = callback;
  }
  script.src = src;
  head.appendChild(script);
}

appendScript("https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js", function() {
  appendScript("https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.3.0.min.js", function() {
    document.body.innerHTML = 'Loaded jQuery version ' + jQuery.fn.jquery;
  });
});
```

See working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/og3djrb5/11/).

Comment: this is good, but I will need to append more than 2 scripts so not sure if appendScript(appendScript(appendScript(appendScript(...it will be a good ideea, also some of them, like `owl-carousel` will append only if I need it

Comment: You will need to keep nesting the `appendScript()` calls if each script depends on the next.